# Using "Codable" to set property values doesn't work through inheritance

Tags: swift, codable

I am unable to set the `b` property in a child class.  It is the parent class that inherits from `Codable`, and that seems to be working well.

I feel like I am missing something really obvious, but I am having trouble seeing the wood for the trees.

Below is a playground example of my problem.  `b` remains 0, despite being set to `10`.  It is the child class that gets passed in, but the parent property that can be set (very weird!).

```
class Primary : Codable {
    var a: Int = 0
}

class Secondary : Primary {
    var b: Int = 0
}

let c = Secondary.self

func testRef<T: Codable>(_ t: T.Type) {
    let json = "{\"a\":5, \"b\" : 10}".data(using: .ascii)!
    let testCodable = try? JSONDecoder().decode(t.self, from: json)
    print("a >> \((testCodable as! Primary).a)")
    print("b >> \((testCodable as! Secondary).b)")
}

testRef(c)
```

The output from this is:

```
a >> 5
b >> 0
```

Any tips or pointers would be gratefully received.

- tried in Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1

Comment: structs are automatically Codable but classes aren't. try this: give Primary's var a a non zero value, decode it and see if it works. turn Primary into a struct (and comment out Secondary) and run it again.
What happens?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer since this is just debugging advice.

Comment: Thanks,  but in my case it was specifically classes I was looking to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magic of `Codable` relies on simplicity (using structs which don't support inheritance).

*The more custom, the more code*

You have to write a custom initializer in the **subclass** to consider inheritance (thanks to Hamish for the note that CodingKeys and initializer are synthesized in the base class), I omitted the `Encodable` part intentionally

```
class Primary : Decodable {
    var a: Int

/*
   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case a }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        a = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .a)
    }
*/
}

class Secondary : Primary {
    var b: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case b }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        b = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .b)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}


func testRef<T: Decodable>() throws -> T {
    let json = "{\"a\":5, \"b\" : 10}".data(using: .utf8)!
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: json)
}

do {
    let secondary : Secondary = try testRef()
    print(secondary.a, secondary.b) // 5 10
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Note that the compiler can synthesise an implementation of `init(from:)` and `CodingKeys` for the `Primary` base class, so you can omit those (it just doesn't do the same for subclasses).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I do understand the premise but I must confess to finding it weird that the symptoms are not reversed.  As it is the subclass which is generated and decoded, I would expect that to the be one that would work.  As @Hamish alludes to the reason for this, I'm happy to begrudgingly come to terms with the reality of the situation.  Thank you for the help, you have saved some sanity.